# How to set location of group collapse/expand button in TListView

Tags: windows, listview, winapi, c++builder, vcl

I have a VCL Forms application, containing a `TListview` with `GroupView`=`true`.

I use the following code to give the listview the same visual style as the listview in the Windows File Explorer (Windows 10):

```
SetWindowTheme(ListView1->Handle, _T("ItemsView"), NULL);
```

This changes the look of the group collapse/expand button to match the File Explorer, but the button is always located on the right side of the group header. In File Explorer, the group collapse/expand button is located on the left side of the group header.

How do I get the listview to display the group collapse/expand button on the left side?

Comment: When you create your groups, does setting the `TListGroup.HeaderAlign` property make any difference on the positioning of the collapse/expand button?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Unfortunately not. I also tried changing the `BiDiMode` property of the `TListView`, but this only moves the scroll bar to the left. The collapse/expand button is always located on the right side. Microsoft also uses a listview in File Explorer, so it must be possible...

Comment: @RemyLebeau Using Spy++, I found that File Explorer uses a custom control with window class `DirectUIHWND`, not a standard `SysListView32`. I also found that `TListView` has only one child control; a `SysHeader32` header control.  That means the group headers and collapse/expand buttons are not child controls of the listview. There also doesn't seem to be a(n) (extended) window/listview style flag or message that controls the location of the collapse/expand button.

Comment: Maybe @RaymondChen knows whether it's possible to have a standard `SysListView32` listview display the collapse/expand button  of group headers on the left side instead of the right side?